# Retrieve file association icon for mime type or file extension

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Currently I'm developing an app where at the end of a message I want to show a list with attachments. These attachments can be downloaded and/or opened in some external app on the phone.

I'd like to show some graphic next to the filename, just like your average mail client would do. My question is how do I retrieve the icon associated with a mimetype or file extension. I.e for attachment `spreadsheet.xlsx` I'd like to the 'Office' or 'Excel' logo/icon that's registered with the system.

My googling skills couldn't find any solution working on windows phone 8. I think it should be possible since the documentation describes how to associate your app with a file  including supplying a logo to display. [(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I'd try [StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync) but it's not supported on windows phone 8 but intellisence came up with this line in the documentation: "This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called." It's only supported from WP8.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit**

I know [StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync) is only available from WP 8.1

My question is: is it possible on WP 8.0? I want my app to work on at least WP 8.0 and if possible I want to add WP 7 support as well.

Comment: `StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync` is only available in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: that's why I added the "not supported" section to my question

Comment: I haven't used Windows Phone 8.1 SDK but what project types you have when creating Windows Phone 8.1 project?

Comment: The app must work on WP8 and if possible we're adding WP7 support later on. So I can't use `StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync` since its added with WP8.1

Comment: I don't have experience developing with WP, but can't you just use the same method used by Windows desktop apps?

Comment: WP is a slimmed down version of the 'regular' Windows meaning they cut within the supported functionality and methods. This way its usable on phones that compared to desktops have limited hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're out of luck. Keep an eye on Windows 8.1 user share and drop support for Windows 8.0 if you can, so you can use the `StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync` call.

My solution would be to make a few default icons for the file types that are used most often, with a general fallback to a generic document icon.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like this solution but seams that there is no other way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can register the necessary extensions by editing the manifest file. As mentioned [here](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/a-lap-around-windows-phone-8-sdk-file-association-part-2)

Comment: How can this help me to retrieve other app's logo or icon? I need file icon from _other_ applications not to supply one for my application. To repeat my question: ```I.e for attachment spreadsheet.xlsx I'd like to retrieve the 'Office' or 'Excel' logo/icon that's registered with the system.```

Comment: What i meant to convey was this could be one way to hardcode the logo or icon, since they are not available from the platform api.

Comment: Aha, got your point but it's not possible since windows has [reserved file associations for build-in apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).